# Re use parameters in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
equiper?editeur=editor1,editors2&domaine=domaine1,domaine2
```

I have this URL when my checkboxes in my filter are checked and I would like to use it as a link, i.e. when I click on it, the checkboxes are checked and the filter is applied on my products.

This is the code I have for my filter. I have 4 editors and each have several domaine.
Then #products corresponds to the products.

```html
<div class="hEditeur">
    <input id="editor1" name="editeur" type="checkbox" value="editor1">
    <label for="editor1">Editor1</label>
</div>
<section id="domaine">
    <div>
        <input id="domaine1" name="domaine" type="checkbox" value="domaine1">
        <label for="domaine1">Domaine 1</label>
    </div>
</section>
<article id="products">
    <div data-domaine="domaine1" data-editeur="editor1"><a href="">Some text</a>
</article>
```

**EDIT :**

So I see that I was not clear enough. I can undertand that. Sorry.

This is the page when no checkbox are checked
[Normal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyxCi.jpg)

And this when we have Editor1 check and Domaine2 Check for exemple.
[When check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as2gL.jpg)

Now the URL is equiper?editeur=editeur1&domaine2

I manage to retrieve parameters in variables, but I can't reuse them to check my checkboxes.
For exemple, if 2 editors has check, i can have editeur1,editeur2 together in a variable but not separated.

So if I want to use

```
var edit = getAllUrlParams().editeur
if (edit == "editor1") {
      //some code
    }
```

That's don't work because edit is editor1,editor2, not just editor1.
I don't know if I'm any clearer about my intentions, so don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Not very clear can you rephrase the question so it is easier to understand

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  Adding some javascript?  Reading the url?  Setting checkbox value?

Comment: I agree with others. "Can you help me doing this?" is not a knowledge question. If you got stuck in something specific and actually struggled a bit yourself, you would be able to ask something like "Why can´t I use this method to reuse URL parameters?".

Comment: In fact, I can stock the parameters but not reuse them. Exemple : if editeur have 2 data, I can't serapate them, I can only use both. I'm not very good in javascript but I don't have choise to use it sometimes and for this I don't have the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in order to get the values of the url parameters:

```js
const queryString = window.location.search;         // get the url string
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString); // parse the url parameters
const editeur = urlParams.get('editeur')            // get each url parameter
const domaine = urlParams.get('domaine')
```

then you can separate them and parse each element you want with the html query selector and its properties

Comment: Yes this is something I can do, but if editeur have 2 data, I can't select the first or the second. This is exactly where i'm stuck.

Comment: `editeur.split(",")[0]` and you can get the second by replacing 0 by 1

Comment: Ok, but I try a little to ply with, but I always have error. I thing I missing something